# Systemd service does not print output to console/syslog/journal

Tags: debian, systemd, kernel-modules, systemd-journald

**UPDATED: SEE BOTTOM**

I have created a systemd service on debian Linux with systemd version 241 whose purpose is to start up a compiled `accelMonitor.c` that connects to a kernel module. This kernel module supplies the script with an event in response to a gpio interrupt from an accelerometer. Upon receiving the event, `accelMonitor` prints out the orientation of the device to the console. The systemd unit file that turns the `accelMonitor` script into a service is seen below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Accelerometer Orientation Monitor


[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/etc/systemd/system/deviceFileCreator
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/accelMonitor
RemainAfterExit=true
KillMode=process
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/accelMonitor.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/accelMonitor.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service first executes the compiled `deviceFileCreator.c` script to generate a device file for the kernel module and `accelMonitor` to communicate through. The service then executes the `accelMonitor` script itself which registers with the kernel module through said device file. Currently, the output is being written to the `accelMonitor.log` file. Both the `deviceFileCreator` and `accelMonitor` script use `printf` statements and are written in C.

**My question is in response to this issue**: When the `deviceFileCreator` script is run, the printf statements are logged to the `accelMonitor.log` file properly. However, when the `accelMonitor` script is run, no print statements are properly logged in the .log file, despite both scripts being in c and using printf. I am hoping someone familiar with systemd services can easily spot the reason this is happening by looking at my code below. To be clear, `accelMonitor` prints to console properly when not run as a service.

**What I have tried so far:**

In the service unit file itself, I have tried the following options for `StandardOutput`: `syslog`, `syslog+console`, `console`, `append:/var/log/accelMonitor.log`. None of these options seem to print from `accelMonitor` to console, journal, or .log file. I am certain the `accelMonitor` script is running due to the fact that it is resetting the accelerometer interrupt after it occurs.

I also split the section of `accelMonitor` that creates the device file off into the `deviceFileCreator` script that runs prior just in case that was the issue. It didn't seem to change anything, however once enabled this change causes the `accelMonitor.service` to now print out it is running on bootup (`[  OK  ] Started Accelerometer Orientation Monitor`) where it did not previously (however it still ran eventually).

I have also tried `Type=oneshot` in addition to `Type=simple`.

If anyone can give me some insight into why I am not getting log info from `accelMonitor` but do from `deviceFileCreator` it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**The `deviceFileCreator.c` file is seen below:**

```
// deviceFileCreator.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// Helper function to run bash commands in c
// This allows me to create the device file using terminal commands
char* exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* fp;
    int status;
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    char* regValue;
    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        /* Report error */
        perror("popen error");
    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
        //printf("%s", path);
        regValue = path;

    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status == -1) {
        /* Error reported by pclose() */
        printf("Error reported by pclose()");
    }
    return regValue;
}

int main() {
        int fd;
        printf("Creating Device File irq_signal \n");

        // Command to create device file
        exec("sudo mknod /dev/irq_signal c 64 0");
        /* Open the device file */
        fd = open("/dev/irq_signal", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
                perror("Could not open device file\n");
                return -1;
        }
        printf("Device file /dev/irq_signal created \n");
        return 0;
}
```

Output into the accelMonitor.log when this script runs on boot is:

```
Creating Device File irq_signal
Device file /dev/irq_signal created
```

**The `accelMonitor.c` file is seen below:**

```
/* 
Event handler to monitor signals from 
associated kernel module. Triggers whenever
an interrupt is detected by the kernel module 
(gpio_irq) from the MMA8451Q accelerometer and 
is passed as a signal (SIGTX 44) to this script. 
This occurs everytime the device orientation changes 
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* Signals to connect to Kernel Module */
#define SIGTX 44
#define REGISTER_UAPP _IO('R', 'g')

/* Define registers to be accessed on Accelerometer over i2c */
const char* deviceADDR = " 0x1C";
const char* PL_STATUS = " 0x10";
const char* INT_SOURCE = " 0x0C";
const char* PL_CFG = " 0x11";
const char* PL_COUNT = " 0x12";
const char* CTRL_REG1 = " 0x2A";
const char* CTRL_REG3 = " 0x2C";
const char* CTRL_REG4 = " 0x2D";
const char* CTRL_REG5 = " 0x2E";

/* Defines function structure for i2c-tools package */
const char* cmdGet = "i2cget -y 2";
const char* cmdSet = "i2cset -y 2";

/* Enum for current device orientation state */
enum position { left, right, down, up };
enum position oriented;

/* Function that runs bash commands in c 
Allowing one to use the i2c-tools package */
char* exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* fp;
    int status;
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    char* regValue;

    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        /* Report error */
        perror("popen error");

    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
        //printf("%s", path);
        regValue = path;

    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status == -1) {
        /* Error reported by pclose() */
        printf("Error reported by pclose()");
    }
    return regValue;
}

/* Function that performs i2cget */
char* get(const char* reg1, const char* reg2) {
    char str[100];
    char str2;

    strcpy(str, cmdGet);
    strcat(str, reg1);
    strcat(str, reg2);

    char* regValue = exec(str);
    return regValue;

}

/* Function that performs i2cset */
char* set(const char* reg1, const char* reg2, const char* value) {
    char str[100];
    char str2;

    strcpy(str, cmdSet);
    strcat(str, reg1);
    strcat(str, reg2);
    strcat(str, value);
    //printf("%s\n",str);
    char* regValue = exec(str);
    return regValue;
}

/* Helper function to check whether or not a bit k is set */
bool bitSet(char* x, int k) {
    int n = strtoul(x, NULL, 16);
    //printf("%d\n", n);
    if (n & (1 << (k - 1))) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

/* Event handler for signal from Kernel Module */
void signalhandler(int sig) {

    // Never Prints
    printf("Event Detected");

    // This clears the interrupt, which is how I know the script is functioning
    char* orientation = get(deviceADDR, PL_STATUS);
    if (bitSet(orientation, 2) && bitSet(orientation, 3) && oriented != left) {
        printf("Landscape Left   \n");
        oriented = left;
    }
    else if (!bitSet(orientation, 2) && bitSet(orientation, 3) && oriented != right) {
        printf("Landscape Right  \n");
        oriented = right;
    }
    else if (bitSet(orientation, 2) && !bitSet(orientation, 3) && oriented != down) {
        printf("Portrait Down    \n");
        oriented = down;
    }
    else if (!bitSet(orientation, 2) && !bitSet(orientation, 3) && oriented != up) {
        printf("Portrait Up      \n");
        oriented = up;
    }
}

int main() {
    int fd;
    signal(SIGTX, signalhandler);

    /* Configure the Accelerometer */
    printf("Configuring Accelerometer...\n");
    set(deviceADDR, CTRL_REG1, " 0x00");   // Put in Standby
    set(deviceADDR, CTRL_REG1, " 0x20");   // Set data rate to 50Hz
    set(deviceADDR, PL_CFG, " 0x40");      // Enable orientation detection
    set(deviceADDR, CTRL_REG4, " 0x10");   // Enable interrupts
    set(deviceADDR, CTRL_REG5, " 0x10");   // Route interrupt to INT1 pin
    set(deviceADDR, PL_COUNT, " 0x05");    // Set debounce to 100ms
    set(deviceADDR, CTRL_REG1, " 0x02");   // Set interrupt to Active High
    set(deviceADDR, CTRL_REG1, " 0x01");   // Put in Active Mode
    get(deviceADDR, PL_STATUS); // Read PL_STATUS to clear initial interrupt
    printf("Configured!\n");

        // Also does not print
    printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());

    /* Open the device file */
    fd = open("/dev/irq_signal", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Could not open device file\n");
                return -1;
        }

    /* Register app to Kernel Module */
    if (ioctl(fd, REGISTER_UAPP, NULL)) {
        perror("Error registering app");
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Wait for Signal */
    printf("Wait for signal...\n");
    while (1)
        sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output from `systemctl status accelMonitor.service`**

```
● accelMonitor.service - Accelerometer Orientation Monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/accelMonitor.service; enabled; vendor pre
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-11-17 17:06:52 UTC; 26min ago
  Process: 565 ExecStartPre=/etc/systemd/system/deviceFileCreator (code=exited,
 Main PID: 655 (accelMonitor)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1026)
   Memory: 1.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/accelMonitor.service
           └─655 /etc/systemd/system/accelMonitor

Nov 17 17:06:49 beaglebone systemd[1]: Starting Accelerometer Orientation Monitor..
Nov 17 17:06:52 beaglebone sudo[573]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mknod /dev/irq_signal c 64 0
Nov 17 17:06:52 beaglebone sudo[573]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 17 17:06:52 beaglebone sudo[573]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 17 17:06:52 beaglebone deviceFileCreator[565]: Creating Device File irq_signal
Nov 17 17:06:52 beaglebone deviceFileCreator[565]: Device file /dev/irq_signal created
Nov 17 17:06:52 beaglebone systemd[1]: Started Accelerometer Orientation Monitor.
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `printf("Hello")` I have switched to the explicit `fprintf(stdout,"Hello")` and `fprintf(stderr,"Hello")` version. This works, however I have a new issue where only the stderr stream is printed out, even though both `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` are set to the same setting (`syslog` currently) in the service unit file.

Comment: The answer to my updated issue was solved in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876660/how-to-turn-off-buffering-of-stdout-in-c):